# Subtracting Day from Postgresql EPOCH Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I have the following code where I am trying to simply subtract 5 days from the date. The date is stored as in EPOCH time (miliseconds, 13 numbers)in the t.Date_created field. but for some reason the code does not work with the following error. Any advice would be helpful!!!

> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone -
> integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types.
> You might need to add explicit type casts.

**Code below:**

```
SELECT to_timestamp(t.date_Created / 1000) - 5 FROM task_mgmt.teams t LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: If you are only interested in date then:`SELECT to_timestamp(t.date_Created / 1000)::date - 5 FROM task_mgmt.teams t LIMIT 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract an `interval`

```
to_timestamp(t.date_Created / 1000) - interval '5 days'
```

Integers can only be subtracted directly from a `date` value, not from a `timestamp` value.

Comment: @Blackdynomite: why not store the timestamp as a proper `timestamptz`? Then you can also get rid of the conversion between a `timestamp` value and a `bigint`

Comment: relatively new to this so didn't know that was an option! I will have to investigate how to do that

Comment: @Blackdynomite: `alter table teams alter date_created type timestamp using to_timestamp(date_created/1000);` You might want to read [this](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/) as well

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest arithmetic:

```
t.date_created - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```